# Bazel + numpy + zip cross compile for arm

Tags: numpy, cross-platform, cross-compiling, bazel

I am using bazel to make a python zip (--build_python_zip) from py_binary rule. Works great on the same architecture, but I when I try run the x86 built app it crashes on the arm with:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

I think this is because there are some c libs in numpy that are included but built for x86. From looking around it seems like I need to define a toolchain in bazel and build with that. Does this work with the rules_python pip_install thing? How do I define/use the toolchain?

I have a minimal example in: https://github.com/CruxML/MinimalCrossCompile. Run make_zip.sh to build and run. Verified that this has issue described.

Comment: Can you post a minimal repro (workspace file, build files, minimal source files, bazel commands, etc)? There are some details like how you're depending on numpy, where you're getting it, how you're building it, etc that would be useful to know to try to help.

Comment: Yeah good idea. Done.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been solved in `rules_python` 0.12 and above in [PR #773](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/pull/773)